# nav_menu_item_title stripping most HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert some HTML into the title of menu items, however from my simple tests it does not appear to be working. I am running this code in my functions.php file

```
    function show_menu_item_desc( $title, $item ) {
    if( is_object( $item ) && isset( $item->ID ) ) {
        $title="<span class='blabla'>TEST <br> TEST</span>";
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title', 'show_menu_item_desc', 10, 2 );
```

However it then displays as

```
<span>TEST  TEST</span>
```

However from reading the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_item_title/) on the wordpress website for the nav_menu_item_title filter, the example includes HTML classes. So i am not sure why its being stripped.

Comment: It seems to display exactly what you ask to be displayed. What exactly is stripped? The user comment there uses `$menu_item->classes` to detect if a menu item has children. That doesn't seem relevant to your concern.

Comment: _"the example includes HTML classes"_ - what are you referring to here, I don't see any such thing on the page you linked to?

Comment: There might be other filter functions added to that same hook name already, and perhaps one of those that does HTML escaping, runs after yours? Have you tried increasing the priority of your own add_filter call?